# svg2 specs, when to throw an IndexSizeError Exception?

Tags: svg, specifications

The draft of the SVG2 specificaton (https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/) clearly states the following when working with listInterfaces:

> If index is greater than or equal to the length of the list, then throw an IndexSizeError.

My question is: What happens if you specify a negative index?

Comment: index is unsigned so that's kind of hard to do.

Comment: user can still call `getItem(-1)` - so how would that be handled? I should add that I speak about the Browserimplementation and therefore javascript. There are just numbers...

Comment: you'd actually pass MAX_LONG - 1 to the function. That's just how webidl works though and not really SVG specific.

Comment: I tried in in FF and it just throws an Error (same error as when to high index specified)